# Error when i push in GITLAB (RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error)

Tags: linux, windows, git, http, gitlab

When I push in gitlab, I get the error:

```
cip$ git push  
Counting objects: 2149, done.  
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.  
Compressing objects: 100% (2105/2105), done.  
Writing objects: 100% (2149/2149), 77.28 MiB | 21.82 MiB/s, done.  
Total 2149 (delta 839), reused 0 (delta 0)  
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly  
Everything up-to-date
```

I tried to upsize the PostBuffer. but I get the same error...
When I push the files separated, I don't get the error and the push happens ok.

The problem occurs in windows (10 64x) e Linux (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

An HTTP status code of 500 indicates that the server encountered an error.  This is an issue on the server side, and there's nothing you can do to control it.  If there were an issue that you were capable of controlling, the HTTP status code would start with 4 instead of 5.

You should contact the hosting provider, either GitLab support or whomever is hosting your GitLab instance, and report the issue to them.  They'd be the only ones who can fix it.  If you are using a proxy or MITM device of some sort, you may want to contact the maintainer of that system first or verify that it isn't the source of the problem by connecting from another network.

Note that in general, increasing the `http.postBuffer` size is not effective in solving any sort of problems unless the remote server or a proxy is incapable of speaking HTTP/1.1 or newer properly.  In most cases, increasing it just wastes memory on small pushes.

Comment: The problem is:
Our gitlab is the free version and we mantain it (my team has instaled and make the support)
Only servers is manteined for the infraestruture team

When we get one issue, we need to get a help with community to solve a problem

Comment: You need to look at the logs, then, and figure out why it's returning a 500.  The GitLab documentation has explanations on how the logs work and where they are.